# Tallying variable for points across polygons with sf::st_covers()

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a number of points with a variable and a set of polygon. I want to count the summation of the variable for all points within each polygon. I've been using {sf} to solve this, but it becomes extremely slow for the real life dataset I'm using.

I've been using `tidyr::uncount()` to create a unique POINT for each observation, as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
site_head_counts_sf <- tibble::tribble(
  ~head.count,      ~long,    ~lat,
  5197L, 12.751139,  50.7245,
  3463L,   5.56224, 49.60383,
  6589L,  5.466844, 50.98443,
  8908L,  5.126504, 49.97417,
  6763L,  5.567645, 50.86621,
  2767L, -4.128448, 40.87398,
  8827L, -5.649966, 41.98329
) %>%
  uncount(head.count) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"),
           crs = 4326)
```

For my regions, let's extract some countries from `counties110`

```
some_countries_sf <- countries110 %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  select(name) %>% 
  filter(name %in% c("Germany", "Belgium", "Spain")) %>% 
  rename(country = name)
```

Finally I can calculate the total number of observations as follows:

```
head_count_by_country_sf <- some_countries_sf %>% 
  mutate(covers = st_covers(some_countries_sf, site_head_counts_sf) %>% lengths())
```

My real-life dataset is larger in 3 ways:

- More unique locations in site_head_counts_sf
- Higher "head.count" variables (upwards of 1E6)
- My shapefiles are a hexagonally binned grid of 500 POLYGONS

What's an alternative approach to solving this via `uncount()`? The slow down comes from very large sf objects.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `st_covers()` I realised I could add IDs to the polygons and use `st_intersects()` as follows

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(mapview)
library(rnaturalearthdata)

site_head_counts_sf <- tibble::tribble(
  ~head.count,      ~long,    ~lat,
  10, 12.751139,  50.7245,
  10,   5.56224, 49.60383,
  20,  5.466844, 50.98443,
  30,  5.126504, 49.97417,
  40,  5.567645, 50.86621,
  10, -4.128448, 40.87398,
  1000, -5.649966, 41.98329
) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"),
           crs = 4326)

some_countries_sf <- countries110 %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  select(name) %>% 
  filter(name %in% c("Germany", "Belgium", "Spain")) %>% 
  rename(country = name) %>% 
  mutate(polygon_id = row_number(),
         polygon_id = as.character(polygon_id))


polygon_counts <- site_head_counts_sf %>%
  mutate(
    polygon_id = as.character(st_intersects(geometry, some_countries_sf))
  ) %>% 
  group_by(polygon_id) %>% 
  summarise(total_head_count = sum(head.count)) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry()

new_solution <- some_countries_sf %>% 
  left_join(polygon_counts)
#> Joining, by = "polygon_id"


mapview(list(new_solution, site_head_counts_sf %>% tibble::add_column(total_head_count = NA)),
        zcol = "total_head_count")
```

[image]